# Set the number of grid columns on screen width - jQuery Mobile?

Tags: android, jquery, css, jquery-mobile, mobile

I'm trying to limit the number of Grid columns (Using jQuery Mobile - http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.4.2/grids/) based on the screen width. This is for a fullscreen app that won't be scalable, so no need for a responsive design.

To give you an example, if the app is loaded onto an iPhone 3GS (320w x 480h), would want to limit it to 2 columns only. If loaded onto a Samsung S3 (720w x 1280h), limit to 4 columns. Etc.

Thought about using either the JS document.width or width.screen.width properties but have found them to be too inconsistent. On a Samsung Galaxy S3 running Android the native browser reports the screen width as 720px and Chrome browser reports it as 320px.

Adding and removing the viewport metatag had no effect on the width value from JS.

meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0"

Neither did delaying the lookup with a setTimeout.

Versions of jQuery I'm using:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.2/jquery.mobile-1.4.2.min.css" /> 
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.2/jquery.mobile-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
```

Is there a way to achieve this with CSS?

Thanks.

[EDIT]

Not so sure this is an issue for the app I'm building. In Google Chrome on effected Android versions seeing 4 columns instead of 5 will is definitely 'failing gracefully'.

Answer (score 0):

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, target-densityDpi=device-dpi">
```

See if this fixes it. The galaxy is rendering half the pixels in order to allow the devices graphics card to render the sharpness itself and not continually get desktop websites from sites that use the screen's width to determine the device type when the device is mobile.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. Unfortunately adding those extra couple of properties in the meta viewport tag had no effect on the window.screen.width value in Chrome.

Comment: This [article](http://www.petelepage.com/blog/2013/02/viewport-target-densitydpi-support-is-being-deprecated/) will tell you more about the problem you're dealing with. :) hope it helps

Comment: codykochmann, good article. I'm not so sure this is an issue for the app I'm building, more above in the edit.

Answer (score 0):

So far i know the column number has to be declared hard coded. So it has to be dynamically created to control the number of columns.

```
width=$(window).width();
```

OR

```
width=$( document ).width();
```

And

```
if(width<=320)
{
    myhtml='<div class="ui-grid-a" class="mymenu">"';
    myhtml=myhtml+'<div class="ui-block-a">Hello</div>';
    myhtml=myhtml+'<div class="ui-block-b">Hello</div>';
    myhtml=myhtml+'</div>';

}
else if(width>320 && width<720)
{
    myhtml='<div class="ui-grid-b" class="mymenu">"';
    myhtml=myhtml+'<div class="ui-block-a">Hello</div>';
    myhtml=myhtml+'<div class="ui-block-b">Hello</div>';
    myhtml=myhtml+'<div class="ui-block-c">Hello</div>';
    myhtml=myhtml+'</div>';

}

$('#menu_div').html(myhtml);
```

Comment: Hi AtanuCSE, width=$( document ).width(); is also returning the incorrect value (320px) in Chrome running in Android 4.3.

Comment: then use `width=$(window).width();`

Comment: I did. I also tried making the call after the DOM is ready. Result is always 320px when it should be 720px as reported in the pre-installed browser. The problem appears to be not that any of the JS methods are incorrect, it's that device pixels are not the same as a CSS pixels and that the previous work-around using target-densitydpi is no longer supported in Chrome on Android. More here: http://www.petelepage.com/blog/2013/02/viewport-target-densitydpi-support-is-being-deprecated/